# is it possible to update tables using synonyms

Tags: sql, oracle, synonym

I have synonyms in my database which is refering one table in different DB. Is it possible to update the table using synonymn name?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Speaking only to Microsoft SQL Server, you can update a table in a different database on the same server using a synonym. This behaves the same as using the 3-part name directly in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can update by using below method( for oracle db ):

```
create public database link db2 connect to myschema using 'abc-scan.mycompany.com.tr:1521/db2.mycompany.com.tr';
create synonym syn_table1 for table1@db2;
update syn_table1 set col1=value1
```